# reactjs update parent then update siblings

Tags: reactjs

I was using an example from http://andrewhfarmer.com/component-communication/#3-callback-functions to communicate from a child to a parent.

I'm attempting to create a star rating system with reactjs. It's not updating the state of the siblings when it re-renders.  I've attempted calling `this.forceUpdate()` and `this.render()` when `StarsContainer.onRate()` is called, alas this doesn't fix the problem either.

```
Expected output:
StarContainer render: 5 <-
RATING: 5
Star render: 0 : 5
Star render: 1 : 5
Star render: 2 : 5
Star render: 3 : 5
Star render: 4 : 5
Star render: 5 : 5
Star render: 6 : 5

Actual output:
StarContainer render: 5 <-
RATING: 5
Star render: 0 : 1
Star render: 1 : 1
Star render: 2 : 1
Star render: 3 : 1
Star render: 4 : 1
Star render: 5 : 5
Star render: 6 : 1
```

The debug clearly shows that the parent `StarContainer` is re-rendering, and the state for that component has the rating of 5.  It also shows that the `Star` components are being re-rendered.  However the rating isn't being updated for the "siblings".

Did I find a bug, or is this expected behavior?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>Hello World</title>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@latest/dist/react.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@latest/dist/react-dom.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6.15.0/babel.min.js"></script>
    <style>
        a.star:hover {
            cursor: pointer;
            color: red;
        }
        a.star {
            font-size: 2em;
        }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <script type="text/babel">

        class Star extends React.Component {
            constructor(props) {
                super(props);
                this.state = {
                    rating: props.rating,
                    value: props.value,
                    onValue: props.onValue,
                    offValue: props.offValue,
                    className: props.className,
                    onRate: props.onRate
                };
            }

            handleClick(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                console.log('The link was clicked.');
                this.setState({rating: this.state.value});
                console.log("this.state.value:",this.state.value);
                this.props.onRate(this.state.value);
            }

            render() {
                var rating = this.state.rating;
                var value = this.state.value;
                console.log("Star render:", value, ":",rating);

                if (rating >= value) {
                    return(<a className={this.state.className} onClick={(e) => this.handleClick(e)}>{this.state.onValue}</a>);
                } else {
                    return(<a className={this.state.className} onClick={(e) => this.handleClick(e)}>{this.state.offValue}</a>);
                }
            }
        }

        Star.propTypes = {
          onRate: React.PropTypes.func,
        };

        class StarsContainer extends React.Component {
            constructor(props) {
                super(props);

                this.state = {
                    rating: props.rating,
                    className: props.className
                };
            }
            onRate(newRating) {
                console.log("StarsContainer onRate:", newRating);
                this.setState({rating: newRating});
                console.log("New Rating:", this.state.rating);
            }
            render() {
                console.log("StarContainer render:", this.state.rating, "<-");
                const rating = this.state.rating;
                console.log("RATING:", rating);
                return(<span>
                    <Star rating={rating} value="0" onValue="0" offValue=" " className="star" onRate={this.onRate.bind(this)} />
                    <Star rating={rating} value="1" onValue="+" offValue="-" className="star" onRate={this.onRate.bind(this)} />
                    <Star rating={rating} value="2" onValue="+" offValue="-" className="star" onRate={this.onRate.bind(this)} />
                    <Star rating={rating} value="3" onValue="+" offValue="-" className="star" onRate={this.onRate.bind(this)} />
                    <Star rating={rating} value="4" onValue="+" offValue="-" className="star" onRate={this.onRate.bind(this)} />
                    <Star rating={rating} value="5" onValue="+" offValue="-" className="star" onRate={this.onRate.bind(this)} />
                    <Star rating={rating} value="6" onValue="?" offValue="" className="star" onRate={this.onRate.bind(this)} />
                </span>);
            }
        }

        StarsContainer.propTypes = {
          onRate: React.PropTypes.func,
        };

        ReactDOM.render(
          <StarsContainer rating="1" onValue="+" offValue="-" className="star" />,
          document.getElementById('root')
        );

    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Maybe don’t use `this.state.rating` and instead just use `this.props.rating`: it’ll update when the top component rerenders

Comment: You are correct, all I had to do was change `Star.render()` to `const rating = this.props.rating; const value = this.props.value;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to keep the inner state of your Star (child) component in your case. Only need to keep the inner state of your StarsContainer (parent) and pass it in a callback as what you did to its children.

In your case, you only assign **this.props.rating** to **this.state.rating** in the constructor, that is why every time the component has been re-rendered but didn't change.

I did a quick snippet based on your code. Most of it is removed **this.state.rating** in `<Star />` component and the rest of it is removed some props of `<StarContainer />`.

If you get more familiar with `this.state` and `this.props` then, you will realize why it is called **React**JS.

```js
        class Star extends React.Component {
            constructor(props) {
                super(props);
                this.state = {
                    onValue: props.onValue,
                    offValue: props.offValue,
                    className: props.className,
                    onRate: props.onRate
                };
            }

            handleClick(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                console.log('The link was clicked.');
                console.log("this.state.value:",this.props.value);
                this.props.onRate(this.props.value);
            }

            render() {
                var rating = this.props.rating;
                var value = this.props.value;
                console.log("Star render:", value, ":",rating);

                if (rating >= value) {
                    return(<a className={this.state.className} onClick={(e) => this.handleClick(e)}>{this.state.onValue}</a>);
                } else {
                    return(<a className={this.state.className} onClick={(e) => this.handleClick(e)}>{this.state.offValue}</a>);
                }
            }
        }

        Star.propTypes = {
          onRate: React.PropTypes.func,
        };

        class StarsContainer extends React.Component {
            constructor(props) {
                super(props);

                this.state = {
                    rating: 0,
                    className: props.className
                };
            }
            onRate(newRating) {
                console.log("StarsContainer onRate:", newRating);
                this.setState({rating: newRating});
                console.log("New Rating:", this.state.rating);
            }
            render() {
                console.log("StarContainer render:", this.state.rating, "<-");
                const rating = this.state.rating;
                console.log("RATING:", rating);
                return(<span>
                    <Star rating={rating} value="0" onValue="0" offValue=" " className="star" onRate={this.onRate.bind(this)} />
                    <Star rating={rating} value="1" onValue="+" offValue="-" className="star" onRate={this.onRate.bind(this)} />
                    <Star rating={rating} value="2" onValue="+" offValue="-" className="star" onRate={this.onRate.bind(this)} />
                    <Star rating={rating} value="3" onValue="+" offValue="-" className="star" onRate={this.onRate.bind(this)} />
                    <Star rating={rating} value="4" onValue="+" offValue="-" className="star" onRate={this.onRate.bind(this)} />
                    <Star rating={rating} value="5" onValue="+" offValue="-" className="star" onRate={this.onRate.bind(this)} />
                    <Star rating={rating} value="6" onValue="?" offValue="" className="star" onRate={this.onRate.bind(this)} />
                </span>);
            }
        }

        StarsContainer.propTypes = {
          onRate: React.PropTypes.func,
        };

        ReactDOM.render(
          <StarsContainer onValue="+" offValue="-" className="star" />,
          document.getElementById('root')
        );
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>Hello World</title>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@latest/dist/react.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@latest/dist/react-dom.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6.15.0/babel.min.js"></script>
    <style>
        a.star:hover {
            cursor: pointer;
            color: red;
        }
        a.star {
            font-size: 2em;
        }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="root"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```